# How can I control Rich Text editor profiles in SXA?

Tags: sxa

We're about to implement some changes/restrictions on the Rich Text Editor Profile for our SXA solution. We're also exploring the possibility for letting this be controlled in some way, by the user who is using it.

In investigating this, I noticed that SXA configures `Rich Text` fields with the following source (so Profile) `query:$xaRichTextProfile`.  Where is this ultimately resolved, and is there an in-application way to set this up OOTB without patching token resolver processors etc?

We're on SXA 1.9, Sitecore 9.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Editing.config` and you will find there following processor in the `resolveTokens` pipeline:

```
<resolveTokens>
    <processor type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Editing.Pipelines.ResolveTokens.ResolveEditingTokens, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Editing" resolve="true" />
</resolveTokens>
```

This processor simply replaces the `$xaRichTextProfile` with path to the profile. This path is defined in the same file, the setting is called `XA.Foundation.Editing.DefaultRichTextProfile`.

If you want to allow users to change that, simply add a field somewhere with e.g.: a path to a custom profile. Then replace this processor with one which instead of reading setting will get profile path form that custom field.

Comment: mmh... but then how is this different than the OOTB setting; `<setting name="HtmlEditor.DefaultProfile" value="/sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/Rich Text Full"/>`?

Comment: Or maybe I should ask; why go through the trouble of adding a token resolver and a new setting, only to end up in a zero sum game with what Sitecore already offers?

Comment: You asked where it is resolved and most part of the above text answers that. There is no out of the box "user-friendly" way to change it. But with a custom field somewhere you can e.g.: make it configurable per site.